# How to see the file's encoding in emacs?

Tags: emacs, encoding

I don't find the encoding of current file, how to display it?

[image: emacs]

You can see there are some Chinese characters in the file, but I don't know what the encoding it is.

Is there any way to let it always show on the emacs GUI?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You have several ways to get (and set) the buffer encoding:

- You can see with the `U` in the mode-line that your buffer is in "Unicode", if you put the **mouse over it**, it will show in a tooltip the current buffer encoding.
- you can also see the **current encoding** with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `buffer-file-coding-system` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- you can **change** the whole buffer encoding **for next save** with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
- you can also change the detected encoding to force an other one and **reload the file** with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- you can set an encoding for the next I/O command only with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- there are some other possibilities, take a look on <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>

Fix and diagnose:

- Inside a buffer, if you are interested by a **single character encoding / details**, put the point on a chinese char and <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> will help. (The same without the <kbd>C-u</kbd> shows only a few informations about the character, and the encoding is not part of it.)
- examine the file by yourself:

  - you can open a text file without any decoding or heuristic with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-file-literally`<kbd>RET</kbd>
  - or you can go closer to the metal (hex editor) with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`hexl-find-file`<kbd>RET</kbd> or for current file <kbd>M-x</kbd>`hexl-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>
- if the file is a mess with mixed encodings, **you can fix portions** with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`recode-region`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: you're welcome :o). Emacs is my swiss knife when I must deal with file encodings. The only problem is that it is a long way before being comfortable with it. `C-h a` helps a lot though.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me solve a long-running problem! We could see that some "*" were entered in ascii and others were UTF8, causing errors in some old programs.  Life Saver, you are.