# what's the difference among various types of 'utf-8' in emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode, encoding

In Emacs, after typing

```
M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system
```

I could see many types of 'utf-8', for example, **utf-8**, **utf-8-auto-unix**, **utf-8-emacs-unix** and etc.

I want to know what's the difference among them.

I have googled them but couldn't find a proper answer.

**P.S.**

I ask this question because I encountered an encoding problem a few months ago. I wrote a php program in Emacs and in my **~/.emacs**, I set

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

but when browsing the php page in a browser, I found the browser couldn't display the content correctly due to the encoding problem even though I had wrote

```
<meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the page.

But after I used *notepad++* to store the file in utf-8, the browser could display the content correctly.

So I want to learn more about encoding in Emacs.

Comment: You could always try `hexl-mode` to see how exactly the file is stored. Chances are this has to do with BOM, and possibly, the order of bytes in BOM (there's a variant of UTF-8 where bytes aren't in network order iirc, no one uses it really, but it might be there for completeness).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last part of the encoding name (eg. `mac` in `utf-8-mac`) is usually to describe the special character that will be used at the *end of lines*:

- `-mac`: `CR`, the standard line delimiter with MacOS (until OS X)
- `-unix`: `LF` the standard delimiter for unice systems (so the BSD-based Mac OS X)
- `-dos`: `CR+LF` the delimiter for DOS / Windows

some additional encodings parameters include:

- `-emacs`: support for encoding all Emacs characters (including non Unicode)
- `-with-signature`: force the usage of the BOM (see below)
- `-auto`: autodetect the BOM

You can combine the different possibilities, that makes the list shown in Emacs.

To get some information on type of line ending, BOMs and charsets provided by encodings, you can use `describe-coding-system`, or: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

Concerning the BOM:

- the utf standard defines a special signature to be placed at the beginning of the (text) files to distinct for the `utf-16` encoding the order of the bytes (as utf-16 stores the characters with 2 bytes - or 16 bits) or endianess: some systems place the most significant byte first (big-endian -> `utf-16be`) some others place the least significant byte first (little-endian -> `utf-16le`). That signature is called *BOM*: the *Byte Order Mark*
- in `utf-8`, each character is represented by a single byte (excepted for extended characters greater than 127, they use a special sequence of bytes) thus specifying a *byte order* is a nonsense but this signature is anyway usefull to detect an utf-8 file instead of a plain text ascii. An utf-8 file differs from an ascii file only on extended chars, and that can be impossible to detect without parsing the whole file until finding one when the pseudo-BOM make it visible instantly. (BTW Emacs is very efficient to make such auto-detection)
- FYI, BOMs are the following bytes as very first bytes of a file:

  - utf-16le : `FF FE`
  - utf-16be : `FE FF`
  - utf-8 : `EF BB BF`
- you can ask Emacs to open a file without any conversion with `find-file-literally` : if the first line begins with `ï»¿` you see the undecoded utf-8 BOM
- for some additional help while playing with encodings, you can refer to [this complementary answer "How to see encodings in emacs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500323/how-to-see-the-files-encoding-in-emacs/10500912#10500912)

As @wvxvw said, your issue is a probable lack of BOM at the beginning of the file that made it wrongly interpreted and rendered.
BTW, `M-x hexl-mode` is also a very handy tool to check the raw content of the file. Thanks for pointing it to me (I often use an external hex editor for that, while it could be done directly in Emacs)

Comment: Thank you very much! After I revert the encoding from **utf-8** to **utf-8-with-signature** in Emacs, the mobile browser *chrome* could display the php page correctly. I find [this page](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-2) and I know that **Where a BOM is used with UTF-8, it is only used as an encoding signature to distinguish UTF-8 from other encodings** . And I have a question that why **utf-8&BOM** works while **utf-8** doesn't on the mobile browser chrome but they both works on PC chrome. Is it the flaw of the mobile browser chrome?

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html), I typed **C-x <RET> utf-8-with-signature <RET>** but it couldn't convert the file from the code of the file to **utf-8-with-signature** unless I modify the **~/.emacs** file and set the code utf-8-with-signature. Is there an easy way to convert the code of a file to **utf-8-with-signature** in Emacs?

Comment: @flyer: you must have a typo: to specify an encoding for a command, you must follow `C-x RET` with either `f` (encoding used while saving), `r` (reload the file with the encoding) or `c` (encoding for the next command). If I open an ascii file then `C-x RET f utf-8-with-signature RET` followed by `C-x C-s` the file is saved in the new encoding (Emacs24)

Comment: thank you for your help. I did as you have said, but it still couldn't help unless I modified the `~/.emacs` file. My Emacs version is 24.2.1.

Comment: I have also the windows 24.2.1 here. Not sure how to help further... What shows `C-h v buffer-file-coding-system` after you try a `C-x RET f` operation?

Comment: I just found why the command couldn't help. I set `(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)` in `~/.emacs` and this overrode the variable `buffer-file-coding-system` which makes `C-x RET f` ineffective. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

Can't say much about the issue, except that after setting

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

I haven't had any unicode problems for more than 2 years.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. After setting the encoding **utf-8-with-signature**, it works. :D

Comment: I use: 

(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)

The help for coding-system-for-{read,write} says that you shouldn't use those.

Comment: I think the doc refers to package writers not to the user. I mean I would't be happy if some package changed this preference for me. But I do know how I want my files read and saved.