# How to make a GitHub README.md render

Tags: github, readme

I have a `README.md` here but it is not showing up as rendered Markdown, it just shows the raw text. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

https://github.com/slothdude/soundcloud-groupme-bot/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to reliably detect a file's encoding. At the end of the day, it's a guessing game.

That particular file is stored in some strange encoding. Some editors (e.g. Emacs) seem to mostly open it successfully (though there are a few strange characters that might be whitespace), but don't know what it is. When I [ask Emacs what encoding it's using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10500912/354577) I get `no-conversion`, which [isn't very helpful](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Coding-Systems.html).

Others, like Gedit, show what looks like a mixture of [kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) and rectangular symbols suggesting unknown values.

Tools like `file` and [`enca`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) seem to have no idea what it is:

```
$ file README.md
README.md: data
$ enca README.md
enca: Cannot determine (or understand) your language preferences.
Please use `-L language', or `-L none' if your language is not supported
(only a few multibyte encodings can be recognized then).
Run `enca --list languages' to get a list of supported languages.
```

Open it in a decent text editor (ideally the one you've used to author it) and save it as UTF-8, then commit that change. I suspect that this will fix its rendering on GitHub.

Comment: Conversion of characters to UTF-8 helped me. Thanks!